# How do I know when the user dismisses my notification on the watch?

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to be notified if a notification that has appeared on the watch is dismissed form the watch? The application that has created the notification may need to know that to react accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deleteIntent on your notification will still be triggered, even if it was dismissed on a remote device.